# Scikit-learn: equality constraints on parameters

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to implement logistic regression with some equality constraints on parameters. For example, if the decision boundary is:
a0+a1x1+a2x2+a3x3+a4x4=0 and I need a1=a4. How do I implement this with scikit-learn

Comment: This is currently not possible as far as I know

Comment: Can I add a function to implement this? I have tried using scipy.optimize.minimize but it doesn't give good results

Comment: Yes you could extend their LogisticRegression class, but this is not trivial. After reading your question again, are you sure you want to do Logistic Regression?

Comment: Yes logistic regression is necessary. How do I extend the LogisticRegression class

Comment: Take a look at the source code of sklearn and look at Python inheritance for class extention